# How to create an android notification based on a local xml file time value?

Tags: android, notifications

How can I implement a notification functionality on an android app in which at a set time found on an xml, the app will display a notification?

Say a local xml file has a value which say notifyat=5:00pm, so I want the app to everyday, display a notification based on that value?

I have been reading through this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html

How can I get the app to automatically read the xml file everyday and show me the notification at the specified time?

Comment: This isn't what "push notification"s are.

Comment: So what should I be looking at for what I want my app to do?

Comment: I think you're okay, just know that those notifications are just called "notifications". Push notifications are something a server sends a client, which I presume is not what you're doing.

Comment: No, I am not working with a server but with local data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do something like this you are going to need to use an AlarmManager.  Here is an example of running your code at this specific time:

```
    // create intent
    launchIntent = new Intent(this, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, launchIntent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    long interval = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1); // the interval is one day
    long firstTime = 0;

    // create a Calendar object to set the real time at which the alarm
    // should go off
    Calendar alarmTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    alarmTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
    alarmTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    alarmTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    // set the alarm for today at 5pm if it is not yet 5pm
    if (now.before(alarmTime)) {
        firstTime = alarmTime.getTimeInMillis();
    } else {
        // set the alarm for the next day at 5pm if it is past 5pm
        alarmTime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        firstTime = alarmTime.getTimeInMillis();
    }
    // Repeat every day at 5pm
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstTime, interval,
            pendingIntent);
```

The "MyAlarmReceiver" class is where you will put your code that launches your notification.  Make sure to declare your BroadcastReceiver class in the AndroidManifest.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So in this example MyAlarmReceiver would be the class that actually launches the notification?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  There are other ways to do it, i.e. Service, IntentService, but this is one option that will work.  You just put the code you want to run (your notification) in onReceive() in your BroadcastReceiver class.  The AlarmManager will signal the BroadcastReceiver which will run your notification.